# Each link should open a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click and select the first a in the `mainPart`, I have to select the first `subLink` div in the `secondPart` div.. so other `subLink` classes are not show.. And it should be in that order.. second a.link selected,  second `sublink` selected.... with jquery

```
<div class="mainPart">
  <a  href="#" title="" class="link selected">first link</a>
  <a  href="#" title="" class="link">second link</a>
</div>
<div class="secondPart">
  <div  class="subLink selected">
    <a  href="#" title="" class="lmLink">....</a>
    <a  href="#" title="" class="lmLink">....</a>
  </div>
  <div  class="subLink">
    <a  href="#" title="" class="lmLink">....</a>
    <a  href="#" title="" class="lmLink">....</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What jQuery have you tried?

Comment: Well that's a nice introduction of what you want  but what have you tried? This isn't a free writing service. Please edit your question and include the relevant source code "Your javascript/jQuery attempt(s)". Thank you.

Comment: [link](http://onedio.co/)  More tab on the menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use index for that, by getting the clicked anchor index then select the div with the same index in the `secondPart` :

```
$('.mainPart>a').on('click', function(){
    var index = $(".mainPart>a").index($(this));

    $('.secondPart .subLink').hide().eq(index).show();
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.mainPart>a').on('click', function(){
   var index = $(".mainPart>a").index($(this));
  
   $('.secondPart .subLink').hide().eq(index).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainPart">
  <a  href="#" title="" class="link selected">first link</a>
  <a  href="#" title="" class="link">second link</a>
</div>
<div class="secondPart">
  <div  class="subLink selected">
    <a  href="#" title="" class="lmLink">1.1...</a>
    <a  href="#" title="" class="lmLink">1.2...</a>
  </div>
  <div  class="subLink">
    <a  href="#" title="" class="lmLink">2.1...</a>
    <a  href="#" title="" class="lmLink">2.2...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can achieve the same effect without javascript by making use of [**`:target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo selector in CSS, adding `id` attribute to the `.subLink` divs, like below:

[**jsFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/sbbasu1n/2/)

```css
.subLink {
  display: none;
}
.subLink:target {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainPart">
  <a href="#sub1" title="" class="link selected">first link</a>
  <a href="#sub2" title="" class="link">second link</a>
</div>
<div class="secondPart">
  <div id="sub1" class="subLink">
    <a href="#" title="" class="lmLink">first 1</a>
    <a href="#" title="" class="lmLink">first 2</a>
  </div>
  <div id="sub2" class="subLink">
    <a href="#" title="" class="lmLink">second 1</a>
    <a href="#" title="" class="lmLink">second 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Update:**

For the `hover` event with some javascript, using jQuery [**`hover()`**](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function:

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/sbbasu1n/3/)

```js
$('.mainPart a').hover(function() {
  $('.subLink' + $(this).attr('href')).show();
}, function() {
  $('.subLink' + $(this).attr('href')).hide();
})
```

```css
.subLink { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainPart">
  <a href="#sub1" title="" class="link selected">first link</a>
  <a href="#sub2" title="" class="link">second link</a>
</div>
<div class="secondPart">
  <div id="sub1" class="subLink">
    <a href="#" title="" class="lmLink">first 1</a>
    <a href="#" title="" class="lmLink">first 2</a>
  </div>
  <div id="sub2" class="subLink">
    <a href="#" title="" class="lmLink">second 1</a>
    <a href="#" title="" class="lmLink">second 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea nice.. thank you  but on mouse over ? is that Possible with css ?

Comment: Done, with javascript/jQuery help